# Has anyone split db read and writes OSCommerce or any php shopping cart?

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce, oscommerce

We are modifying [osCommerce](http://www.oscommerce.com/), but our architecture involves separate clusters for db reads and db writes.

Has anyone separated these out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you guys looked at mysql proxy? you could use it to automatically send reads and writes to the correct server, even for applications you can't modify.

additionally, you can use the [`master_pos_wait()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_master-pos-wait) function to keep your reads and writes synchronized. (when you do a write, get the log position from that master, then issue master_pos_wait() to the slave to wait for it to catch up)